# Finding Uniqueness (duplicates)

Tags: java, unique

Im having trouble with my `isUnique` method. Either I'm making a logical error or a syntax error, or both. I have to make sure that every user input I get is Unique. Everything else I have done is correct but that method. I was using the debugger and I've noticed that the "number" doesn't change as the  user input changes but I am new and kinda lost. Assigment: Enter 5 numbers and test for validity and uniqueness. If not valid do not count towards 5 numbers. If not unique count towards 5 numbers but count number of unique and print "not unique" if not unique.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4Part2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = new int[5];

        System.out.println("Enter an integer (50-100): ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int uniqueCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length;) {

            {
                numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
                if (isValid(numbers[i]) == true) {
                    i++;

                    if (isUnique(numbers, numbers[i]) == true) {
                        uniqueCount++;
                        System.out.printf("Unique so far: %d ", uniqueCount);

                    }
                    if (isUnique(numbers, numbers[i]) == false) {
                        System.out.println("That's not unique.\n");
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)

        {
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int array) {

        if (array <= 100 & array >= 50) {
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println(" ***Invalid Number\n");
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static boolean isUnique(int[] array, int numbers) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == numbers) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need 5 unique numbers by input?

Answer (score 0):

some things i notice:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length;) {

        {
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
            if (isValid(numbers[i]) == true) {
                //i++; // in case you increment here, you do it before is unqique is true... so next isUnique is of an emtpy (null) numbers[i]

                if (isUnique(numbers, numbers[i]) == true) {
                    uniqueCount++;
                    System.out.printf("Unique so far: %d ", uniqueCount);
                    //continue here
                    i++;

                }// why not an else?
                //if (isUnique(numbers, numbers[i]) == false) {
                else {
                    System.out.println("That's not unique.\n");


                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and the is unique....

```
public static boolean isUnique(int[] array, int numbers) {
   // here the given number is already in the array, so never unique....
   // this will always return false, because the input is already in the array

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == numbers) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

so use:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length;) {

        {
            // use a temp value before putting it in the array
            int input = input.nextInt();
            if (isValid(input) == true) {
                //i++; // in case you increment here, you do it before is unqique is true... so next isUnique is of an emtpy (null) numbers[i]

                if (isUnique(numbers, input) == true) {
                    uniqueCount++;
                    numbers[i] = input
                    System.out.printf("Unique so far: %d ", uniqueCount);
                    //continue here
                    i++;

                }// why not an else?
                //if (isUnique(numbers, numbers[i]) == false) {
                else {
                    System.out.println("That's not unique.\n");


                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and in the is unique function....

```
if (array[i] == numbers) {
```

while not all numbers are filled in... this compares:

```
if(null == numbers){
```

so will be shorter to add in front:

```
if(array[i]==null){
     break;
}
```

because the rest is still empty

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `for` in your method `isUnique`, during the first iteration you compare your the given number with the first value and if they dont match you already return true so the loop can't check any of the remaining numbers.

Just remove the `else` parte in that `if` and change the last `return` out of the loop to a true instead of false.

This way only until you checked the the whole array you will be sure the number is unique.

I would also sugest you send to that methis `uniqueCount` so you dont check the whole array, but just the amount of numbers already registered.